# Find the eigenvalues for a matrix which is a product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Suppose I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2, 2}$ which is the product of $3$ other matrices, lets call them $A_1 = \left(\begin{matrix} cosx & -sinx \\ sinx & cos x\end{matrix}\right)$, $A_2= \left(\begin{matrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 7\end{matrix}\right)$ and $A_3 = \left(\begin{matrix} cosx & sinx \\ -sinx & cos x\end{matrix}\right)$. So the situation is:
$$A = A_1 \cdot A_2 \cdot A_3$$

Now, I am asked to find the eigenvalues for this matrix $A$ **without multiplying $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$**.

In general, if we assume that we don't want zero eigenvectors, then we can find the eigenvalues solving the *characteristic polynomial*, which can be found by assuming (actually it is a consequence) that:
$$\det{(\lambda \cdot I - A)} = 0$$

Then we solve for $\lambda$.

Now, my situation is the following:

$$\det{(\lambda \cdot I - A_1 \cdot A_2 \cdot A_3)} = 0$$

I have found the determinant of $A$, using a property of the determinants, but I don't see any property that can help me to find the determinant just above...

Comment: I can't see how you can make any progress without there being a relationship between $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ of some sort. Is $A_3$ the inverse of $A_1$ or anything of that sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** 
$$\det (\lambda I -A_1A_2A_1^{-1})=\det (\lambda A_1A_1^{-1} -A_1A_2A_1^{-1}) = \det ( A_1 (\lambda I -A_2)  A_1^{-1}) \\= \det (A_1) \det (\lambda I -A_2) \det (A_1^{-1})$$

Answer (score 0):

Similar to comment above, I don't think that the question is properly well defined.

For instance, based on the example in the post below, the eigenvalue of AB cannot be determined by the eigenvalues of A and B. This is related to the diagonalization of a matrix, which basically tells us that a matrix is only uniquely determined when BOTH its eigenvectors and eigenvalues are specified.

[Eigenvalues of Matrices and Eigenvalue of product of Matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716990/eigenvalues-of-matrices-and-eigenvalue-of-product-of-matrices)

On a related note, the question could be solved without multiplying the matrices if we diagonalize every matrix separately. In 2 dimensions, we have the time property that all rotations commute ($SO_2$ is abelian). From there, I think we can express the eigenvalues of ($A_1 A_2 A_3$) as a function of the individual eigenvalues and the angle of the eigenvectors of the composite matrices.

Is this the form of the solution that you are looking for? If so, I can work out the details.