# Geometric interpretation of spectra equality of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, intuition

Following [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716990/eigenvalues-of-matrices-and-eigenvalue-of-product-of-matrices), let $A$ and $B$ be square $n\times n$ matrices. It is a well known **fact** (e.g., 12.3 at [1]) that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues (spectra):

The proof is trivial for $\lambda=0$ in case it is an eigenvalue. If $v$ is an eigenvector of $AB$ which belongs to $\lambda\neq 0$ then $A(Bv)=\lambda v\neq\vec{0}$, and so $Bv\neq \vec{0}$. It is then easy to see that $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $BA$ which belongs to the very same $\lambda$.

While the proof is straightforward, why should one expect this to be true? I'd be glad to have a geometric explanation to this **fact**.

[1] *Golan, Jonathan S.*, [**The linear algebra. A beginning graduate student ought to know**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-94-007-2636-9), Dordrecht: Springer (ISBN 978-94-007-2635-2/pbk; 978-94-007-2636-9/ebook). xii, 497 p. (2012). [ZBL1237.15002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1237.15002).

Comment: In the case that $A$ is invertible, the operation $A^{-1}(AB)A = BA$ can be interpreted geometrically as a change of basis.  This doesn't quite account for the case in which both matrices are singular, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues. Say $ABv = \lambda v$, with $v\ne 0$.  Then $B(AB)v = \lambda Bv$. Assume that $\lambda \ne 0$. Then from the first equation we get $Bv \ne 0$. So now we got $Bv$ a $\lambda$ eigenvector for $BA$. This trick unfortunately does not account for multiplicities.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how Golan proves that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same spectra. But that does not answer my questions.