# Eigenvalues of $AB$ in terms of $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\ \text{and}\ B$ be two $n\times n$ matrix. Where $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ and $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Now can we describe eigenvalues of AB in terms of eigenvalues of A and B?

Comment: No. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/716990) for instance.

Comment: I understood. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: In general no, because the matrices do not share their Eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general you can say nothing. But there may be some specific circumstances where you can say something:

**Case 1:** all the eigenvalues of $B$ are nonzero.

In this case, $B$ is invertible. Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix with entries $r_1, \ldots, r_n$, and let $A = DB^{-1}$. Then $AB = D$, i.e., AB has the $r$s as eigenvalues, and those could be anything.

**Case 2:** $k$ of the eigenvalues of $B$ are zero.

In this case, at least $k$ of the eigenvalues of $AB$ are zero as well, for if $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ for the eigenvalue $0$, i.e, if $Bv = 0$, then
$$
(AB)v = A(Bv) = A0 = 0
$$
as well. The remaining $n-k$ eigenvalues can be prescribed just as in Case 1, although it takes a little bit more work to show this.