# Eigenvalues of matrix A, given the eigenvalues of AB and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assuming we know the eigenvalues of both $AB$ and $B$.
Is there any way of determining the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$?

More precise formulation of my problem: I have two non-hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$ such that:

1. $AB$ is stable (i.e. all eigenvalues have negative real part)
2. All eigenvalues of $B$ are equal to 1    (i.e. $\lambda(B)=1$ and $\det(B)=1$)

Intuitively, I would think that this implies that A is stable too (since $\det(AB)=\det(A)$). However I have not been able to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ is the only relationship between the eigenvalues of $AB$ and those of $A$ and $B$. See my previous [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/717086) for instance.

Your intuition about the stability of $A$ is also untrue. Consider e.g.
$$
A=\pmatrix{-1&-3\\ 1&1+t},\ B=\pmatrix{1&-2\\ 0&1},\ AB=\pmatrix{-1&-1\\ 1&-1+t}.
$$
When $t>0$ is small, $AB$ is stable because it is a small perturbation of $\pmatrix{-1&-1\\ 1&-1}$, but $A$ isn't stable because it has a positive trace.

Comment: This answers my question, thank you!