# Eigenvalues of polynomial are polynomial of eigenvalues for block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field, $n,s\ge1$ integers, and $B\in M_{ns}(F)$ an $ns\times ns$ matrix over $F$. Let $A_1, \ldots, A_n\in M_s(F)$ be $s\times s$ matrices over $F$, and let us consider the following polynomial $P(X)\in M_{ns}(F)[X]$:
$$ P(X)= \begin{bmatrix}  A_1 &  \\ & A_1 & & \\ & &...
                     & \\
& & & A_1      \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}  A_2 &  \\ & A_2 & & \\ & &...
                     & \\
& & & A_2      \end{bmatrix} X + \ldots + \begin{bmatrix}  A_n &  \\ & A_n & & \\ & &...
                     & \\
& & & A_n      \end{bmatrix} X^{n-1} $$
Given the eigenvalues of $B$, can we describe the eigenvalues of $B'=P(B)$?

If $s=1$, then $P$ can be viewed as a polynomial with scalar coefficients. This case was considered [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492070/how-to-prove-eigenvalues-of-polynomial-of-matrix-a-polynomial-of-eigenvalue), where it was shown that the eigenvalues of $B'$ are than obtained by applying the polynomial to the eigenvalues of $B$. I am interested in finding out whether this can be generalised to block matrices.

Comment: In view of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/716990), I think what you seek is hopeless.