# Properties of the eigenvalues of $A \cdot B$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Take two (real) matrices $A$ and $B$, where both have (real) eigenvalues within the unit circle, $B$ is also a diagonal matrix.

Can I say something about the eigenvalues of the product $A \cdot B$ ?

I suspect that the eigenvalues of $A \cdot B$ are also within the unit circle. Any help/reference for a proof of that?

Thanks

Comment: Just an observation, which is weaker than what you need: The spectral radius is bounded from above by $\|AB\|$, and in turn $\|AB\|\le \|A\|\|B\|$. If both $A$ and $B$ had a norm bounded by $1$, this would imply that the product's spectral radius is bounded by $1$ as well. However, from your assumptions it is likely, but not necessary, that $\|A\|\le 1$ (since $B$ is diagonal, you do know that $\|B\|\le 1$). I don't know if there is a counter-example for the case $\|A\|>1$.

Comment: So, you are saying that if I can prove that ||A||<1, then I know that the eigenvalues of AB are within the unit circle. Right?

Comment: The spectral radius of $AB$ can be arbitrarily large. See my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/717086) to another question for an illustration.