# Is $[F(x)]^{-1}=F(-x)$ obvious for the given matrix $F(x)$?

Tags: matrices

> $$F(x)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos x&-\sin x&0\\\sin x&\cos x&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Is it very obvious (in the sense that without any calculations) that $[F(x)]^{-1}=F(-x)$?

My book directly writes this without any explanation. How is this evident without calculation?

Comment: If I am not mistaken this matrix describes a rotation around a certain angle $x$. The inversion of this would be indeed the rotation around the angle $-x$ which overall makes it pretty clear that $F^{-1}(x)=F(-x)$.

Comment: @mrtaurho Actually its not in rotation context (Maybe it implies rotation, I don't know). Also, I am a beginner. Don't know much about rotation matrices ;-/

Comment: see here maybe? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/716578/515527 and here for some intuition + explanation https://math.stackexchange.com/q/363652/515527

Comment: One way to assert this is by noticing that $F(x)^TF(x)=I$ for any $x$, so the inverse of $F$ is the transpose of $F$ (meaning that it's orthogonal). The matrix $F$ satisfies $F(x)^T=F(-x)$, using the symmetries of sine and cosine. This proves the claim.

Comment: @JoshB. Interesting approach. How could one notice that $F^T(x)F(x)=I$ without computing the product? Is it sufficient to deduce this relation yet alone from the fact that $|F(x)|=|F^T(x)|=1$$($which I would claim is directly viewable from the matrix itself$)$?

Comment: I highly recommend watching this youtube playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab , chapters 3, 4, and 5 are of high relevance to this question. The presentation of the geometric intuition behind central concepts in linear algebra is excellent for someone new to the subject, in my opinion.

Comment: @mrtaurho To be honest, I'm not really sure how to notice this in general, since I mainly knew to do this from experience. Part of it is the fact that each column has a magnitude of $1$, which may ask the question "is this matrix orthogonal?" As you said, since the matrix norm for both $F$ and $F^T$ are both $1$, this also implies that the inverse could be the transpose, but doesn't guarantee it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is obvious if you know multiplication by blocks and the matrix of a rotation (of angle $x$) *in the plane*:

$$R(x)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos x&-\sin x\\\sin x & \cos x\end{bmatrix}, \qquad R(x)^{-1}=R(-x)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos x&\sin x\\-\sin x & \cos x\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now, consider your matrix as a block matrix:
$$F(x)=\begin{bmatrix}R(x)&\mathbf 0 \\
\mathbf 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$
where $\mathbf 0$ denotes the null $2{\times} 1$ column vector in the first row and the null $1{\times}2$ row vector in the second row . Using block multiplication, we see at once that this matrix is invertible and its inverse is
$$F(x)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}R(x)^{-1}&\mathbf 0 \\
\mathbf 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}R(-x)&\mathbf 0 \\
\mathbf 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 2):

This matrix $F(\theta)$ represents a linear transformation that fixes the $z$ axis and rotates the $xy$-plane by an angle of $\theta$ around the origin. The inverse mapping is of course therefore fixing $z$ and rotating the $xy$-plane by an angle of $-\theta$, which is precisely $F(-\theta)$!